# Circuitbreakerevents managment endpoint not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have resilience4j config and have managementconfig also.

`management.endpoint.circuitbreakerevents.enabled=true`

But I can't see any events because URL not found. http://localhost:8080/circuitbreakerevents

`{"timestamp":"2022-09-07T13:23:29.661+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/circuitbreakerevents"}`

http://localhost:8080/health is working and I can see Circuit breaker is up

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#events-endpoint), The path for accessing the CircuitBreaker events is `/actuator/circuitbreakers`

Also make sure the endpoint is exposed by adding this property: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`